# EF6 Code First: Inserting an inherited entity fails

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance

I have an entity called `Client` which fails to insert.
`Client` inherits from `Person` inherits from `Party`.

Here is my model classes:

```
 public class Client : Person
    {
        public Client()
        {
            CrimeIncidents = new List<CrimeIncident>();               
            Reseller = new Reseller();
        }

        public virtual ICollection<CrimeIncident> CrimeIncidents
        {
            get;
            set;
        } 

        public virtual Reseller Reseller { get; set; }

    }

public class Person : Party
    {
        [CustomValidation(typeof(PartyRoleCustomValidation), "ValidateRSAIDNumber")]
        public string IDSocialSecurityPassNum { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Name")]
        public string NickName { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Full names")]
        public string FullNames { get; set; }

        public string Surname { get; set; }

        public Gender? Gender { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Date of birth")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public string DOB { get; set; }

    }

public class Party
    {

        public Int64 Id { get; set; }

        public virtual PartyRole PartyRole
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        //public List<Address> Adresses { get; set; }
        public virtual string PostalAddress { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.PostalCode)]
        public virtual string PostalCode { get; set; }

        public virtual string PhysicalAddress { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.PostalCode)]
        public virtual string StreetCode { get; set; }

        //public List<EmailAddress> EmailAdresses { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        public virtual string EmailAddress { get; set; }


        //public List<ContactNumber> ContactNumbers { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
        public virtual string CellNumber { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
        public virtual string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
        public virtual string FaxNumber { get; set; }



    }
```

Here is the unit test, which fails on the assert statement (a manual check in the database confirms the unit test outcome):

```
        [TestMethod]
        public void AddClient()
        {
            JCGunsDbContext db = new JCGunsDbContext();
            int initCount = db.Clients.Count();

            string guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

            Client cl1 = new Client();
            cl1.NickName = guid;
            cl1.Surname = guid;
            cl1.CellNumber = "0123456789";
            cl1.EmailAddress = "test" + guid + "@test.com";
            db.UserId = "SYSTEM_UNITTESTING";
            db.Clients.Add(cl1);
            db.SaveChanges();

            Assert.IsTrue(db.Clients.Count() > initCount);
        }
```

Why is this insert not working and how do I fix it?

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting?

Comment: Does similar code work in the application? It is very unlikely for `SaveChanges` not to throw an exception when an unexpected number of records is saved.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the Id the the client if this client is connected to an existed Person.
 Otherwise you need to add Person object in the `client.Person` navigation property.

e.g.

Case you're connecting this client to an existed Person.

```
Client client = new Client();
client.Id = oldPerson.Id
```

Case you're adding new client with new Person.

```
Client client = new Client();
client.Person = new Person(){......}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the following statement within the constructor of `Client`:

```
Reseller = new Reseller();
```

Reseller is supposed to be optional.  Setting a new Reseller instance which did not adhere to it's own annotated validation criteria caused the SaveChanges method to fail without throwing an exception.  Removing the statement fixed the problem.